# Changing jTable cell color by value

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

According to all the examples I've looked at my code should work. Why isn't it working?
I am able to change the cell color in my table if i specify a row and column but it's not working if I specify a value.
Here is what I have:

```
//Custom renderer to color table cells red
//cellValue = 00:00:00 - a LocalTime in the table, so all cells with that value should be red.

 public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if (value == cellValue) { 
                c.setForeground(Color.red);
            } else {
                c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
```

Please help before I go nuts!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (value == cellValue)
```

Don't use "==" to compare objects.

Instead you should be using the equals(...) method:

```
if (value.equals(cellValue))
```